# Struct not being defined as a type

Tags: c

```
struct test {
  int id_number;
  int age;
};

test *tester() {
    struct test *test1 = malloc(sizeof(test));
    test1->id_number = 10;
    test1->age = 1;
    return test1;
}

int main()
{
    test *tester = function();
    printf("%d %d \n",tester->id_number tester->age );
}
```

So I'm trying to do some testing with malloc() and structs, but when I try to run my tester code I get an error saying unknown type test, however i am defining the struct test.

Comment: Your type is `struct test`, not `test`.

Answer (score 0):

When referencing a `struct` type, you need to use the `struct` keyword:

```
struct test *tester() {
   ...
}
```

If you want to be able to use `test` as a type, you need a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct test {
  int id_number;
  int age;
} test;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type is called `struct test`, unless you add a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct test test;
```

You can combine the two, this is very common:

```
typedef struct {
  int id_number;
 int age;
} test;
```

This is very common; notice that the "struct tag" can be omitted.